# nesting before and afterVariableChanged calls in optaplanner

Tags: java, entity, drools, optaplanner

Im am using the optaplanner framework to solve an optimization problem.

There is a planning entity "offering" that has a planning variable "volume". There is another JavaBean property called "price" which is a function of the volume.

Isn't it possible to change both properties "price" and "volume" in one go when changing the "volume" during the solution run?

The offering class has among other things the "volume" setter

```
setVolume(int volume) {
    this.volume = volume; 
    recalculatePrice();
}
```

I am using a custom move class that extends AbstractMove to change the volume

```
protected void doMoveOnGenuineVariables(ScoreDirector sd) {
    sd.beforeVariableChanged(offering, "volume"); 
    offering.setVolume(volume);
    // volume was passed to constructor on creation
    sd.afterVariableChanged(offering, "volume");
}
```

During the optimization run I do see the price being changed, but the end price of the solution is always the initial price that was set when Offering was created (The price property is used by the drools engine to calculate the score).

I also have tried to make price a planning variable and to implement doMoveOnGenuineVariables differently:

```
protected void doMoveOnGenuineVariables(ScoreDirector sd) {
    sd.beforeVariableChanged(offering, "volume"); 
    sd.beforeVariableChanged(offering, "price"); 
    offering.setVolume(volume);
    sd.afterVariableChanged(offering, "price");
    sd.afterVariableChanged(offering, "volume");
}
```

or

```
protected void doMoveOnGenuineVariables(ScoreDirector sd) {
    sd.beforeVariableChanged(offering, "volume"); 
    offering.setVolume(volume);
    sd.afterVariableChanged(offering, "volume");

    sd.beforeVariableChanged(offering, "price"); 
    offering.recalculatePrice();
    sd.afterVariableChanged(offering, "price");
}
```

but non of the approaches works.

Comment: recalculatePrice() sounds like a custom **shadow variable** (see docs)

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet, thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for!